# I am getting an error while running rake run:android

Tags: ruby, multithreading, udp, rhomobile

I am attaching following error while i am running my app using the command rake run:android . I am developing this using Rho Mobile(Ruby) and i am also using ruby threads for connecting server it is totally UDP Protocol based communication between server and client

```
D:\Rhomobile\Workspace\Ruby\RTG>rake run:android   
D:\Rhomobile\Workspace\Ruby\RTG>rake --trace
cd C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-4.1.1
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/FileUtils.rb:93: warning: alr
eady initialized constant OPT_TABLE
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/FileUtils.rb:1268: warning: a
lready initialized constant S_IF_DOOR
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/FileUtils.rb:1496: warning: a
lready initialized constant DIRECTORY_TERM
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/FileUtils.rb:1500: warning: a
lready initialized constant SYSCASE
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/FileUtils.rb:1619: warning: a
lready initialized constant LOW_METHODS
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/FileUtils.rb:1625: warning: a
lready initialized constant METHODS
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'default'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rak
e/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rak
e:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.1.1/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Can any one please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you didn't use the correct command to build your app:

```
rake --trace
```

You should use (as you mentioned) the complete command:

```
rake run:android
```

Comment: I have already done it got some issues to identify the issue i tried with rake --trace

Comment: So you should only append the trace parameter and keep the original command: "rake run:android --trace"